# How to access a client's camera using their IP and VideoStream source?

Tags: python, tkinter

My program accepts client connections and store their IP addresses in a list. When a button is pressed, that same list is called in another function that uses said IPs to set VideoStream Source as the clients' camera.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import traceback

from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2

class GUI2(): #loads UI and initializes the server to be connected to

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.PORT = 5000
        
        self.SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        
        
        self.ADDRESS = (self.SERVER, self.PORT)
        
        
        self.FORMAT = "utf-8"
        
        
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                            socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       
        self.server.bind(self.ADDRESS)


        self.master2 = tk.Toplevel() #packs window

        self.ecdpower = tk.Button(self.master2, text = "On/Off", command = lambda: Thread(target = self.startstream).start())
        self.ecdpower.pack() #button used to supposedly start camera
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.startChat)

        self.thread.start() #automatically starts the server when UI is loaded
    
    def startChat(self):
    
        print("server is working on " + self.SERVER)
    
        # listening for connections
        self.server.listen(30)
    
        try:
    
            while True:
    
                
                    self.conn, self.addr = self.server.accept() #accepts connections from clients
                    
                    self.clients.append(self.addr[0]) #gets the client's IP address from the tuple _RetAddress; tuple format is (IP, PORT)
    
                    for y in self.clients:
    
                        print (f"Address is {y}") #To check if list is not empty
                    
        except:
    
            pass 
    
    def startstream(self): #runs when a button is pressed
    
        try:
    
            for x in self.clients:
    
                vs = VideoStream(src = "rtsp://" + x + "").start() #sets the VideoStream source as the clients' camera
    
                   #using their IP address and hopefully be able to view them
    
                while True:
                    
                    frame = vs.read()
                    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1080 )
    
                    cv2.imshow("Eye Close Detection Using EAR", frame)
    
    
        except Exception as e:
    
            print (traceback.format_exc())
```

Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File 
"f:\project\mainmenu.py", line 352, 
in startstream     frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1080 )   
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize     (h, w) = image.shape[:2] 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'.
```

I'm testing the program with 2 terminals in VS Code; one is the server while the other is the client.

Based from the error, it appears that the camera isn't being accessed; hence, the NoneType. Moreover, the program doesn't work if I use `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` to get the IP; it only works if `vs` source is 0 i.e. `vs = VideoStream(src = 0).start()`

I need to be able to access cameras using the client's IP address. Any way to fix or other alternatives?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you print x[0] before the faulty line to check exactly how it looks ? The error message implies it's a tuple. As it is it's hard to help you because we have no reproducible example.

Comment: @Swifty Svlr. It appears that the code functions; I was editing the code while the program was running so the changes didn't fully take effect until I shut down and ran the terminal again. I apologize.

However, a new error now popped up: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\project\mainmenu.py", line 352, in startstream
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1080 )
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`.

Comment: @Swifty I will edit the post to reflect the new error I'm experiencing; it looks like I'm not able to access the IP's camera with my program.

Comment: Make sure the URL is valid, i.e. default port for RTSP protocol is used in client side because there is no port specified in your URL. Any path is needed after the IP address in the URL? You can test the URL using VLC player.

Comment: @acw1668 I've tried looking in VLC, no RTSP URL available; it looks like my camera isn't an IP one. Is there a way to access a client's camera even if it's not IP? I'm actually new to this stuff and learning on the fly; I thought using an IP only is the correct way to go. Do I put the Port number in the VideoStream source?

Comment: For my VLC player 3.0.16, it supports opening RTSP URL via menu `Media -> Open Network Stream...`. As I don't have camera supporting RTSP, I cannot test it